# rename a file using bcp command in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to export the result of an sql server query into a file.

For this purpose I use the bcp command

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from customer  " queryout C:\test\test.txt -T -c'
```

However, I need to name the file with the result of getdate(), i.e.

```
queryout C:\test\test#getdate()#.txt -T -c'
```

Can any one know if we can do it ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable and then use it as a parameter for xp_cmdshell, something like

```
declare @cmd varchar (1000)

set @cmd = 'bcp ... C:\test\test.txt' + convert(varchar, getdate(), 112) + ' -T -c'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Comment: You could of course do the concatenation at the parameter too, it's not necessary to have a variable

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @dt varchar(50) = (SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50),getdate(),120),':','-'))
DECLARE @cmd varchar(2000) = 'bcp "select * from customer " queryout "C:\\test\\' + @dt + '.txt" -T -c'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```